# Loading latex package in Python (particularly for variants of a symbol/letter)

Tags: python, latex, symbols

Is it possible to load a Latex package (like using `\usepackage`) inside a python code? For example,  I want to generate [a variant font of the Greek letter \tau](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40210/how-to-specify-variant-tau/40219#40219).

Detexify suggests loading `upgreek` package in Latex and then using `\uptau` for the symbol.

If it is not possible, what could be an alternative way?

Comment: Finally after a few more searches, I found `pgf`  to be useful in the `matplotlib` context and this link has some working examples :  https://matplotlib.org/users/pgf.html .

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with those characters?

As far as I'm aware python won't natively support this, as it's not able to print those characters to the shell. It only [natively supports unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#definitions). There are some greek characters available.

If you want to display them then [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Exactly, I want to use it in the legends/labels of a plot. (Do I need to edit my question?)

Comment: Then I would follow the matplotlib link; you'll probably have to have your own LaTeX build it rather than use the built-in one if you want to use packages though. You can find more details on that [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#usetex-tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, but the links doesn't tell how to load TeX packages. I found using `pgf` is useful and demos can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/pgf.html). For my example, I have tested with `\upgreek` package and successfully rendered `\uptau` symbol. :)

Answer (score 0):

Modern TeX engines support fonts in TrueType (ttf) and OpenType (otf) format.

Using the [Python bindings](https://www.cairographics.org/pycairo/) ([example](https://www.cairographics.org/cookbook/pycairo_pango/)) to the `cairo` and `pango` libraries, you should be able to use these fonts.

Alternatively, you could use [freetype-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/freetype-py). This will load characters from fonts as bitmaps.

Which one works best for your purpose is hard to say without further information on what you want to do with the fonts.
If you want to output small amoumts of text in PDF or SVG format, `cairo` would be the way to go.

To the best of my knowledge, neither Python (nor cairo) can deal with MetaFont fonts.

A third way would be for your script to output (La)TeX code, and let the TeX engine render it. This would be my choice if you had to render a large amount of text because TeX can then deal with things like formatting, line breaking hyphenation and other typesetting related issues.